# Limit textfield input to 1 and hide cursor on textfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

In my application i have a view to enter a 4 digit passcode using 4 textfields.when user touches first textfield and enters 1st character the control should automatically go to the 2nd and so on ..after 4th the validation should happen.Also the user should not be able to see the cursor when he touches textboxes.how to do this?

Comment: Everyone I know who's done one of these has scrapped using a `UITextField` instance and made their own out of buttons and labels, so maybe consider that as an approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if( [textField.text length]==0)
    {
        [nextText becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:      (NSRange)range     replacementString:(NSString *)string
    { 

    if(theTextField == wordTextField1) {
    [wordTextField1 setText:string];
     if(string.length == 1) {
     [wordTextField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
     }
    else if(theTextField == wordTextField2) {
    [wordTextField2 setText:string];
    if(string.length == 1) {
    [wordTextField3 becomeFirstResponder];
     }
       }
         else if(theTextField == wordTextField3) {
       [wordTextField3 setText:string];
    if(string.length == 1) {
    [wordTextField4 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    }
      else if(theTextField == wordTextField4) {
      [wordTextField4 setText:string];
      if(string.length == 1) {
      [wordTextField1 becomeFirstResponder];
     }
     }
    }
```

Comment: the text is limited but cursor not hidden...also when click on first textfield is ok..then control goes to second one there also the 1st textfield entry is coming that is same text is coming....this can be solved if cursor is hidden...i think